# Check if undirected graph is connected

Tags: c, algorithm, graph

I have been making an algorithm that builds a Minimum Spanning Tree where I insert the number of cities (vertexes), airports (edges connecting to a "sky" vertex - vertex 0) and the number of roads (edges connected to other cities).

I then insert the city the airport (source vertex) is built and the cost (edge cost).
After this, I insert the cities connected by roads (source and destiny vertexes) and the cost (edge cost).

The outputs are the MST cost, the number of airports and number of roads.

I already have these mechanisms working but they are a bit buggy. I can't seem to fix these issues.

Also, I was wondering if I can make a function that detects if the undirected graph in the MST is connected (all vertexes are connected). If the function detects that the MST is not connected, the program should output "Insuficient information.".

Full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// A structure to represent a weighted edge in graph.
struct Edge {
    int src, dest, weight;
};

// A structure to represent a connected, undirected and weighted graph.
struct Graph {
    // V -> Vertex Number (Number of cities), E -> Number of edges (Number of roads + airport connections).
    int V;
    int E;
    // The graph is represented as an array of edges.
    // Since the graph is undirected, the edge
    // from src to dest is also edge from dest
    // to src. Both are counted as 1 edge here.
    struct Edge* edge;
};

// Creates a graph with V vertexes and E edges.
struct Graph* createGraph(int V, int E)
{
    struct Graph* graph = malloc(sizeof *graph);
    graph->V = V;
    graph->E = E;
    graph->edge = (struct Edge*)malloc(E * sizeof(struct Edge));
    return graph;
};

// A structure to represent a subset for union-find.
struct subset {
    int parent;
    int rank;
};

// A utility function to find set of an element (uses path compression technique).
int find(struct subset subsets[], int i)
{
    // Find root and make root as parent of i (uses path compression technique).
    if (subsets[i].parent != i)
        subsets[i].parent
            = find(subsets, subsets[i].parent);

    return subsets[i].parent;
}

// A function that does union of two sets of x and y (uses union by rank).
void Union(struct subset subsets[], int x, int y)
{
    int xroot = find(subsets, x);
    int yroot = find(subsets, y);

    // Attach smaller rank tree under root of high rank tree (Union by Rank).
    if (subsets[xroot].rank < subsets[yroot].rank)
        subsets[xroot].parent = yroot;
    else if (subsets[xroot].rank > subsets[yroot].rank)
        subsets[yroot].parent = xroot;

    // If ranks are same, then make one as root and increment its rank by one.
    else
    {
        subsets[yroot].parent = xroot;
        subsets[xroot].rank++;
    }
}

// Compare two edges according to their weights.
// Used in qsort() for sorting an array of edges.
int myComp(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    struct Edge* a1 = (struct Edge*)a;
    struct Edge* b1 = (struct Edge*)b;
    if (a1->weight > b1->weight) {
        return a1->weight > b1->weight;
    }
    if (a1->weight < b1->weight) {
        return a1->weight < b1->weight;
    }
    if (a1->weight == b1->weight) {
        return a1->weight == b1->weight;
    }
}

// The main function to construct MST using Kruskal's algorithm.
void KruskalMST(struct Graph* graph)
{

    int V = graph->V;
    struct Edge
    result[V]; // Saves the resulting MST.
    int e = 0; // An index variable, used for result[].
    int i = 0; // An index variable, used for sorted edges.

    // Step 1: Sort all the edges in non-decreasing order of their weight.
    // If we are not allowed to change the given graph, we can create a copy of array of edges.
    qsort(graph->edge, graph->E, sizeof(graph->edge[0]),
            myComp);

    // Allocate memory for creating V ssubsets.
    struct subset* subsets
        = (struct subset*)malloc(V * sizeof(struct subset));

    // Create V subsets with single elements.
    for (int v = 0; v < V; ++v) {
        subsets[v].parent = v;
        subsets[v].rank = 0;
    }

    // Number of edges to be taken is equal to V-1.
    while (e < V - 1 && i < graph->E) {
        // Step 2: Pick the smallest edge.
        // And increment the index for next iteration.
        struct Edge next_edge = graph->edge[i++];

        int x = find(subsets, next_edge.src);
        int y = find(subsets, next_edge.dest);

        // If including this edge does't cause cycle,
        // include it in result and increment the index
        // of result for next edge.
        if (x != y) {
            result[e++] = next_edge;
            Union(subsets, x, y);
        }
        // Else discard the next_edge.
    }
    int minimumCost = 0;
    int nRoads = 0;
    int nAirports = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < e; ++i)
    {
        if (result[i].dest == 0) {
            nAirports++;
        } else {
            nRoads++;
        }
        minimumCost += result[i].weight;
    }
    printf("Minimum Spanning Tree with minimal cost: %d\n",minimumCost);
    printf("Number of airports: %d\n",nAirports);
    printf("Number of roads: %d",nRoads);

    return;
}

int main()
{
    int v = 0; // Number of vertexes(cities) in the graph (includes the "sky" vertex).
    int a = 0; // Number of airports.
    int edges = 0; // Number of roads.
    int e = 0; // Number Total number of edges in the graph.
    int city = 0;
    int airport = 0;
    int city1 = 0;
    int city2 = 0;
    int cost = 0;

    printf("Input the number of cities: \n");
    scanf("%d", &v);
    printf("Input the number of airports: \n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("Input the number of roads: \n");
    scanf("%d", &e);

    edges = a + e;

    if (a > 0) {
        v = v + 1;
    }

    struct Graph* graph = createGraph(v, edges);


    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        printf("Input the city and the building cost of the airport: \n");
        scanf("%d %d", &city, &airport);

        graph->edge[i].src = city;
        graph->edge[i].dest = 0; // "sky" vertex.
        graph->edge[i].weight = airport;
    }

    for (int j = a; j < edges; j++) {
        printf("Input the cities and the cost of the road: \n");
        scanf("%d %d %d", &city1, &city2, &cost);
        if (a == 0) {
            graph->edge[j].src = city1 - 1;
            graph->edge[j].dest = city2 - 1;
            graph->edge[j].weight = cost;
        } else {
            graph->edge[j].src = city1;
            graph->edge[j].dest = city2;
            graph->edge[j].weight = cost;
        }
    }

    KruskalMST(graph);

    return 0;
}
```

Example of a bug - 0 airports declared but still counts an airport:

```
Input the number of cities:
4
Input the number of airports:
0
Input the number of roads:
4
Input the cities and the cost of the road:
1 2 1
Input the cities and the cost of the road:
2 3 2
Input the cities and the cost of the road:
3 4 1
Input the cities and the cost of the road:
4 1 1
Minimum Spanning Tree with minimal cost: 3
Number of airports: 1
Number of roads: 2
```

The expected number of airports should be 0.

Comment: How is your program "buggy"? It would be nice if you could give a (short) example input togeher with the expected and actual output.

Comment: Okay, give me a second

Comment: The comparison function for `qsort` is three-way: The result should be negative, if `a < b`; positive if `a > b` and zero if `a == b`. You have implemented a two-way `a > b` greater-than function.

Comment: In the MyComp function, correct?

Comment: There's already a function doing that. It's the Union function. It does a similar thing to what you said.

Comment: Hm. If you have no airports, an edge like `3 4 1` is invalid, no? Because in that case, you have only 4 vertices (0, 1, 2 and 3) and vertex 0 is not the sky, but the first city.

Comment: I guess you're right. I had that before but, when I showed that part to my teacher, she said it was wrong. So, I tried to change it.

Comment: The `Union` function does some disjoint set stuff. I mean `MyComp`, which is used by `qsort` internally and must obey the rules I've outlines above. (You can print the sorted edges. They will not always be sorted by weight.)

Comment: If you leave vertex 0 if you have no airports, it will not be connected to the graph.  You could fix the index problem at input and output: Internally use 0, 1, 2, ..., but when reading input or when writing output adjust it, so that 1 is always the first city. Your input should probably enforce that the cities are valid, too. On the subject of the connectivity check: You can do a depth-first search on the first vertex. Keep an array of "visited" flags. If you have unvisited cities after your DFS, your graph isn't connected.

Comment: I edited the code so that ```MyComp``` does what you specified. Also, on the DFS matter, I tried to implement it before but I wasn't able to. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Alternatively, your MST-finding algorithm will determine whether the graph is connected as a side effect.  It has to track the separate connected components as it builds up the MST, for which it uses a disjoint union.  When that algorithm finishes, you should be able to test whether all the vertices belong to the same element of the union.

Comment: So, what you're saying is that if the subsets are different, that means that the MST isn't fully connected?

Comment: Yes.  That two vertices are connected via the MST is what belonging to the same element of the union *means* (as disjoint unions are used in this kind of algorithm).  Tracking connected components is the whole point of using a disjoint union here.

Comment: Yes. John's suggestion is better than mine, because the data is already there. Your representation of edges, where you have to look at all edges to find the connectivities for a certain vertex, isn't really suited to depth-first search. You could mate the Kruskal function return an error value if the tree isn't connected and write an error message in main in that case.

Comment: Edited the code. If it's not what you meant, I will try to rectify it asap

Comment: I was not suggesting that you need to modify your `Union()` function, and in any case, you cannot return a value from it as long as its return type is `void`.  My comments were directed at using the final union *data*, which it looks like you track in a variable named `subsets`.  I have not analyzed your code fully enough to recommend specifics.

Comment: Oh okay, I understand. If you don't have time to analyze the code, it's okay.

Comment: (I've now noted that you actually do the "input adjustment" thing. But in your case, the code in the Kruskal function counts connection to the first city as airport, because it doesn't know ehether tere are air connections or not. You could pass an "airport flag" or the airport index (0 or the inexistent -1, say) to Kruskal or you could make it part of the graph struct.)